# Jquery autocomplere not working in IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have used code from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default which is working fine in FF and Chrome but **not working for IE8 version 8.0.7600.16385**. The developer console states

> 'null' is null or not an object

What's wrong?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.XXX.XXX.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>    

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
    $(function () 
    {
        var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input type="text" id="tags" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get an error in the console? What happens when you debug? Does your computer explode? What happens if you move your `.autocomplete()` declaration to last in the HTML document? DOM load order matters.

Comment: yes, in developer tools in IE, i am getting   "'null' is null or not an object" error.. and getting same error even after moving it last in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved with using internal Jquery files and noconflict function.

```
<script src="/JqueryPlugins/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JqueryPlugins/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JqueryPlugins/ui/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JqueryPlugins/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$J = jQuery.noConflict();
$J(function () 
{
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];
    $J("#tags").autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
});
</script>
```